# How to send mails to new Drupal users after 1,7,20 days

Tags: email, drupal

When new users sign up on my Drupal website, I would like to send them some tips-and-tricks emails. First mail after one day, another day the next week and another email after two weeks.

Is there a plugin (or a set of plugins) that can do this? I want to avoid hacking too much PHP.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, and its Scheduler module

Comment: And don't forget to configure cron.